# Class loading from /bin/content instead standalone/deployments

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, jersey, classloader

i run my war in jboss as 7.1.1. it uses jaxb/jersey. when i deploy the war i get this error:

```
14:32:55,162 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/PostecomBusiness]] (MSC service thread 1-8) Servlet /PostecomBusiness threw load() exception: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) [jersey-bundle-1.11.jar:1.11]
```

this is the web.xml with jaxb configuration:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC  
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"  
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >  

<web-app>  
    <display-name>Postecom Business</display-name>  

   <listener>  
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>  
   </listener>  

   <listener>  
         <listener-class>it.eng.postecom.listener.ContextListener</listener-class>  
   </listener>  

    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>jax-ws</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  

    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>jax-rs</servlet-name>  
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
         <init-param>  
              <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>  
              <param-value>it.eng.core.service.server</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>  
      </servlet>  

      <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Servlet di inizializzazione</servlet-name>  
        <display-name>Context Config Servlet</display-name>  
        <servlet-class>it.eng.postecom.module.config.ContextInitServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  

    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>PostecomWS</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>PostecomWS</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/PostecomWS</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
           <servlet-name>jax-rs</servlet-name>  
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
      </servlet-mapping>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>jax-ws</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/soap/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <context-param>  
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>  
        <param-value>false</param-value>  
    </context-param>  
    <context-param>  
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>  
        <param-value>false</param-value>  
    </context-param>  
    <context-param>  
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>  
        <param-value>false</param-value>  
    </context-param>  
</web-app>
```

i debug jersey classes. it gets the right value for com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages but when in PackageNamesScanner.scan it executes the following instruction:

```
final Enumeration<URL> urls = ResourcesProvider.getInstance().getResources(p.replace('.', '/'), classloader);
```

(classloader is an instance of ModuleClassLoader) the result variable urls is:

```
[vfs:/C:/Jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/PostecomBusiness.war/WEB-INF/lib/core-module-0.0.1-20141003.121243-271.jar/it/eng/core/service/server/]
```

but this path doesn't exist: my war is deployed in standalone/deployments. So he can't find the classes.

This is my standalone.xml. (is jboss using the jaxb inside my war or is it using his own jars?) Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">  

    <extensions>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>  
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>  
    </extensions>  

    <management>  
        <security-realms>  
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">  
                <authentication>  
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>  
                </authentication>  
            </security-realm>  
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">  
                <authentication>  
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>  
                </authentication>  
            </security-realm>  
        </security-realms>  
        <management-interfaces>  
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">  
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>  
            </native-interface>  
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">  
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>  
            </http-interface>  
        </management-interfaces>  
    </management>  

    <profile>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">  
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">  
                <level name="INFO"/>  
                <formatter>  
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>  
                </formatter>  
            </console-handler>  
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">  
                <formatter>  
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>  
                </formatter>  
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>  
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>  
                <append value="true"/>  
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>  
            <logger category="com.arjuna">  
                <level name="WARN"/>  
            </logger>  
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">  
                <level name="WARN"/>  
            </logger>  
            <logger category="sun.rmi">  
                <level name="WARN"/>  
            </logger>  
            <logger category="jacorb">  
                <level name="WARN"/>  
            </logger>  
            <logger category="jacorb.config">  
                <level name="ERROR"/>  
            </logger>  
            <root-logger>  
                <level name="INFO"/>  
                <handlers>  
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>  
                    <handler name="FILE"/>  
                </handlers>  
            </root-logger>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">  
            <datasources>  
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">  
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>  
                    <driver>h2</driver>  
                    <security>  
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>  
                        <password>sa</password>  
                    </security>  
                </datasource>  
                <drivers>  
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">  
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>  
                    </driver>  
                </drivers>  
            </datasources>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">  
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="10000"/>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">  
            <session-bean>  
                <stateless>  
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>  
                </stateless>  
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>  
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>  
            </session-bean>  
            <pools>  
                <bean-instance-pools>  
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>  
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>  
                </bean-instance-pools>  
            </pools>  
            <caches>  
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>  
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>  
            </caches>  
            <passivation-stores>  
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>  
            </passivation-stores>  
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>  
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">  
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>  
            </timer-service>  
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>  
            <thread-pools>  
                <thread-pool name="default">  
                    <max-threads count="10"/>  
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>  
                </thread-pool>  
            </thread-pools>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">  
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">  
                <local-cache name="entity">  
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>  
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>  
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>  
                </local-cache>  
                <local-cache name="local-query">  
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>  
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>  
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>  
                </local-cache>  
                <local-cache name="timestamps">  
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>  
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>  
                </local-cache>  
            </cache-container>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">  
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>  
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>  
            <default-workmanager>  
                <short-running-threads>  
                    <core-threads count="50"/>  
                    <queue-length count="50"/>  
                    <max-threads count="50"/>  
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>  
                </short-running-threads>  
                <long-running-threads>  
                    <core-threads count="50"/>  
                    <queue-length count="50"/>  
                    <max-threads count="50"/>  
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>  
                </long-running-threads>  
            </default-workmanager>  
            <cached-connection-manager/>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">  
            <show-model value="true"/>  
            <remoting-connector/>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">  
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">  
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">  
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>  
            </mail-session>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">  
            <properties>  
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">  
                    1  
                </property>  
            </properties>  
            <capabilities>  
                <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>  
                <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>  
                <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>  
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>  
                <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>  
            </capabilities>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">  
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">  
            <security-domains>  
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">  
                    <authentication>  
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">  
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>  
                        </login-module>  
                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">  
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>  
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>  
                            <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>  
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>  
                        </login-module>  
                    </authentication>  
                </security-domain>  
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">  
                    <authorization>  
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>  
                    </authorization>  
                </security-domain>  
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">  
                    <authorization>  
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>  
                    </authorization>  
                </security-domain>  
                <security-domain name="form-auth" cache-type="default">  
                    <authentication>  
                        <login-module code="it.eng.utility.authentication.module.LoginModuleImpl" flag="required">  
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="users.properties"/>  
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="roles.properties"/>  
                        </login-module>  
                    </authentication>  
                </security-domain>  
            </security-domains>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">  
            <core-environment>  
                <process-id>  
                    <uuid/>  
                </process-id>  
            </core-environment>  
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>  
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">  
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>  
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">  
                <alias name="localhost"/>  
                <alias name="example.com"/>  
            </virtual-server>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">  
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>  
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>  
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>  
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">  
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">  
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>  
                </pre-handler-chain>  
            </endpoint-config>  
        </subsystem>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>  
    </profile>  

    <interfaces>  
        <interface name="management">  
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>  
        </interface>  
        <interface name="public">  
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>  
        </interface>  
        <interface name="unsecure">  
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>  
        </interface>  
    </interfaces>  

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">  
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>  
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>  
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>  
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>  
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>  
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>  
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>  
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>  
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>  
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>  
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">  
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>  
        </outbound-socket-binding>  
    </socket-binding-group>  

</server>
```

Answer (score 0):

i delete

```
<init-param>  
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>  
          <param-value>it.eng.core.service.server</param-value>  
    </init-param>
```

and it works, so i don't know the reason and if it could be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Deploying the WAR as an exploded directory under the deployments directory helps.